# SSH automatic login invalidation

Tags: security, unix, authentication, ssh

Let's say I have two unix machines, `shell1` and `shell2` and I want to connect automatically without password from `user1@shell1` to `user2@shell2`.

So I execute `ssh-copy-id -i /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user2@shell2`, confirm host adding and insert `user2` of `shell2` password and I have automatic ssh login. Good!

But my question is: what happens if `user2@shell2` changes password? Will the automatic login behave as before or will I have to register again `user1@shell1` against `user2@shell2`?

Comment: ssh pub key access is a separate authentication mechanism from password auth against an NIS or shadow/passwd.

Comment: Ok, considering that I am not an Unix expert could you please translate your reasoning in an answer with the practical consequences of it so I can evaluate it? TIA

Comment: I think Matt's answer is pretty clear.  SSH key-based authentication is unrelated to password authentication.   Once you have installed the ssh keys, it doesn't matter what the password is on the target account.  The only way to disable access would be to remove the public from `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSH public/private key authentication is independent of passwords you set.
The key stored(as authorized keys) on the machine you want to connect matches with the private key of the user trying to connect.
for example.

```
#!/bin/bash 
#here the user is ubuntu
mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/.ssh
echo 'ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDBR1l4eRUrSK4YPruFtV0Z5rVYCeZN/aTv69fWScP1PHTRHc0hlK2NL97RmDQq6oCgkUibbBWdKx+jfjlu2UxNhWOTIeW3SIiVxLyRZTWBcwyaUfn2LOQO6DVuUfc+D2crBCRCI61xUHHx8ObamhW8FjWWugbBa2bdP8JcMu4H/jr+nOVfRE99n/FLUdDoiClDQpJOh1YzNwbHNZdkxrEaTuLbPF+81fGcR3OtSvacJBtldCjjtwnuB/eZ1vMzaa0IiW629amKnEhuhM3wCl8OEX8v++c8ifmxEPmuoVqbg2i1ePPVMJ/zbWerhkAFz4xvYhXCJ0DgLx52MtBw3C2f niks@ubuntu' >> /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys

chown ubuntu.ubuntu /home/ubuntu/.ssh
chown ubuntu.ubuntu /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod go-rwx /home/ubuntu/.ssh
chmod go-rwx /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

This script using your own key and your machine will be ready to connect via ssh.